# anchor flex component at the bottom of the screen in normal mode and full screen mode

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, user-interface

i am a beginner in action script / flex framework and i am facing a problem :

i would like to have like a menu bar always anchor the bottom of the screen in normal and full screen mode ...

i try to set my component with bottom = "1" (so it should alway be at 1 pixel from the bottom of the stage ... But .. NO :)

here my flex xlm :

```
<mx:Canvas>


    <mx:UIComponent id="isoHostContainer" x="0" y="0"  />


    <mx:HBox id="_menu_hbox"  bottom="1" backgroundColor="0Xff0000" borderStyle="solid" borderVisible="true" >
        <mx:Button  label="Zoom +" click="button1_zoom_increase_clickHandler(event)"   labelPlacement="bottom" />
        <mx:Button label="Solid Red"   click="{box1.fill = new SolidColorFill(0xFF2222, 1);}" labelPlacement="bottom"/>
        <mx:Button  label="Transparent"   click="{box1.fill = new SolidColorFill(0xFF2222, 0.2);}" labelPlacement="bottom" />
        <mx:Button  label="Fullscreen toogle" click="button_fullscreen_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <mx:Button  label="Zoom -" click="button2_zoom_decrease_clickHandler(event)"    labelPlacement="bottom"/>           
    </mx:HBox>

</mx:Canvas>
```

if you have the answer it will be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your menu is anchored 1-pixel from the bottom *of your Canvas*, which is retaining the same height..width after you go to full screen.

Try setting your Canvas height=100%.

```
<mx:Canvas height="100%">

<!-- more code below -->
```

This will force the layout engine to resize the canvas when when the application is redrawn full-screen, and in turn, your menu should remain 1-pixel from the bottom.

Caveat: If your Canvas is nested in another fixed-width container, its parent will also need to dynamically resize for this to work.

Comment: What contains the Canvas, out of curiosity?

Comment: isoHostContainer is a view for display isometric data ...
now i do not use canvas :
`code
 <mx:UIComponent height="100%"  id="isoHostContainer"   />
<mx:HBox   id="_menu_hbox" bottom="1" horizontalCenter="1"  backgroundColor="0Xff0000" borderStyle="solid"   borderVisible="true"> 
...
</mx:HBox>`



still the same problem